# How to change font-family with jMenu jQuery's plugin

Tags: jquery, css, jmenu

I'm using the jQuery's plugin "jMenu". I don't manage to change the font-family with CSS :/. I have this css :

```
.jMenu{
    position : absolute;
    top : 80px;
    left : 0px;
    width : 100%;
    display:table;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    font-family : Tahoma;
}
```

Do you have an idea please ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `!important` for forcing your custom `css` font to apply.

```
font-family : Tahoma !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
```

This is the font-family of stackoverflow, maybe you should check the font you use~~~~~